# how to make a plugin secure, so any one if changes something in plugin, it just disables it self and notify us on server?

Tags: plugins

can you please tell me about plugin development,because most of wordpress plugin material referred but no one can define how to make a plugin secure,

so any one if changes something in plugin, it just disables it self and notify us on server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Questions are meant to be references for later visitors as well. Please rework your questions spelling/punctuation/grammar/capitalization so it as as easy to read as possible. Thanks. Aside from that your question is so vague that it can't be answered. Please come up with a specific question that doesn't need a blog post to just cover the basics (and still not delivering something that works as solution).

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to accomplish that.

Your plugin will be coded in php, which means that any part of it can be altered locally at any time. So even if you came up with an efficient way to check for modifications, your checking code would be a part of the plugin, thus just as easy to modify/bypass.

Also, as an aside, not too many people are fond of plugins that "phone home" without permission, [WordPress.org guys least of all](http://wordpress.org/plugins/about/guidelines/) ;).